# How to set iconAnchor at the center of markers icon?

Tags: leaflet, markers, icon

The following is how I can center the markers icon with given size.

```
L.marker(center, {
    icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: `<my-custom-icon.png>`,
        iconSize: [17,36],
        iconAnchor: [8.5,36]
    }),
```

How to reach the same when I have different sizes for markers icon?

I have different markers with different icon size.
I could specify marker iconSize but, as for iconAnchor, I guess if I can set them in a programmatic way.

Any idea?

Comment: Doe's this mean you don't know the size of the icon or that you will not specify icon size with the `iconSize` option or both? Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/475934/edit) your question with additional info.

Comment: Every marker have a different icon and every icon has a different size.

Comment: And I suppose you don't want to/will not specify marker size with the `iconSize` option?

Comment: I can specify marker iconSize but, as for iconAnchor, I guess if I can set them in a programmatic way.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/475934/edit) your question with additional info from your comments so it can be reopened.

Comment: Done. Thank you.